# NextJS + NextAuth + IdentityServer4. Not calling /connect/token endpoint

Tags: next.js, oauth, identityserver4, openid, next-auth

I really don't get what I am doing wrong. Maybe I'm not understanding how it really works..

With NextAuth I'm trying authorize the application with an IdentityServer in Net Core.
I successfully show the login page page from identity server and i can log in (and it redirects to my app, with the `code` in the querystring, but after that NextAuth is not calling the `/connect/token` no matter what I do. Here is my code.

```
export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    {
      id: "custom-provider",
      name: "custom-provider",
      type: "oauth",
      clientId: "nc-setcompany",
      checks: ["pkce", "state"],
      wellKnown: "https://localhost:44392/.well-known/openid-configuration",
      authorization: {
        params: {
          scope: "setcompany.api openid profile",
          redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/callback",
          site: "5485E2C6-A3B4-4129-956F-F1059133CF03",
          response_mode: "query",
          response_type: "code",
        },
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

If I use callbacks, no one is triggered, if I specify de `token` endpoint regarding the documentation, it doesn't call it neither (however they don't recommend it and use well-known instead as I do).

I have tried a lot of configurations, setting session strategy to "jwt", modifying response_mode and response_type, setting params to token endpoint specifically (grant_type: authorization_code) and stuff like that. Nothing worked.

It's not even failing, there is no request at all (chrome console shows no requests to token endpoint).

What i'm missing?

The IdentityServer has this endpoint as its being used successfully by other "`create-react-apps`" (this is our first NextJS app in the company).

This is the part that is not happening at all:

[image]

Do I have to make this call manually from the callback/page.tsx or what? (And yes, I have tried the IdentityServerProvider from NextAuth with exactly the SAME result.)

Comment: when you access https://localhost:44392/.well-known/openid-configuration
this url have much information about token request

Comment: could you please told us you did authorize to login or just want to get connect token

Comment: connect token request is differ its like http call 
curl --location 'https://localhost:5001/connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=xxxxx' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=xxxxx' \
--data-urlencode 'username=tanishk.gupta@xxx.com' \
--data-urlencode 'password=xxxx' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password'

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use HTTPS in the redirect URL http://localhost:3000/callback because the browser will block the cookies when you get the callback to the client due to the samesite settings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried it with using ```npx next dev --experimental-https```, and nothing changed...

Comment: if you have cookie problem, then I suggest you read my blog post here (its for general cookie problems) https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/

Comment: no that's not https problem

Comment: You should use a tool like Fiddler and figure out what step in the authorization code flow that is failing. A successful authentication usually should return a HTML page, with an auto-submitting form.